# JQuery Mobile - Listview - How to use the finger to move an element to the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've created a listview that works well but I would like to add some functionalities to the listview.

Actually, when the user uses his smartphone with his finger, I would like that when the user makes a move with his finger to the right, the `<li>` element slips to the right and that then, the element comes back to his initial place and changes of color.

Is it possible ? Do you have a solution or help ?

Thank you

```
<div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider" data-icon="arrow-d">
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">Les lettres</a>
                </li>

                 <li>a</li>
                  <li>b</li>
                  <li>c</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: search jquery mobile swipe